# Media query issue. Landscape and portrait

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've done a few searches around stackoverflow but none of them seem to address my issue, therefore I'm posting here.

I have a table. It had six rows. I have done a media query (@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)) so that the table doesn't contort the page when viewing on a mobile phone. The media query itself is essentially just doing display: none; on the tr classes.

The problem I'm having however is that the max-device-width is set to 480px. So naturally one would think that when that is exceeded, the fields would return. My mobile phone (Nokia Lumia 800) has a resolution of 480x800 and so in portrait it should hide the tr's. In landscape however they SHOULD reappear since that would be the resolution 800x480. This is essentially my issue. They aren't reappearing despite having done a viewport test and it saying that it is.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Have you tested the same code in a desktop browser? If you are getting correct behavior there, then perhaps it's a bug in the Lumia browser?

Comment: I like to use `max-width: ...` (without device). For me that works always. `@media only screen and max-width: 480px { ... }`

Comment: can you link up the page that you're having issues with, or perhaps write a quick codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: have you included:
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> ?

Also does this happen when the page is initially loaded in landscape orientation? Or does it only happen when loaded in portrait and then moved to landscape?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what is happening in your code is when users are below 480px, you are telling the css to hide the element and the state is saved on run-time.  When the user goes beyond 480px, you don't have a rule to bring this element out of (display:none) state.

CSS works in cascades, so the very last rule given to it would be the one a browser would default to.

If you have a query stating below 480px display: hide,  you would need another query to state above 480px display: block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**For devices  >480px**

```
@media(min-width:481px){
 tr{
    display:table-row ; /* to show table row*/
  }
}
```

**For devices less than 480px**

```
@media(max-width:480px){
 tr{
    display:none;  /* to hide table row*/
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.